# SQL queries: How to confirm with "YES" or "NO"?

Tags: sql, database

I have to do this:
Check out if there is (in a movies database) any "COMEDY". If there is one or more return "YES" else return "NO". I don't know how to express the "YES" and "NO" in select. Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177603.aspx

Comment: i haz teh homeworkz!  If you **can't** use `CASE WHEN` and frankly, I've never heard of a company that doesn't allow it's employees to use `CASE WHEN`, then use a `BIT` or `IF`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way is to use a `CASE` statement:

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM Movies WHERE type = 'Comedy' )
THEN 'YES'
ELSE 'NO' 
END AS answer
```

Or, without `CASE` or `IF`:

```
SELECT TOP 1 Answer
FROM
(
  SELECT 0 AS OrderBy, 'YES' AS Answer FROM Movies WHERE type = 'Comedy'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 'NO' 
)
ORDER BY OrderBy
```

Comment: better than I thought in suggesting

Comment: I am not allowed to use if,case etc. Sorry for not mentioning that...

Comment: @a_user why not?  Is this a puzzle or do you have some REALLY strange coding requirements?

Comment: I don't really know? But thanks, it really helped me!